# Access a mesos-master behind a domain name (not an IP)

Tags: deployment, containers, mesos, marathon

Is it possible to run and access a mesos master on a machine that is placed behind a proxy?

I have successfully succeeded to deployed a MesosMaster/Marathon/MesosSalve on my local infrastructure.

The problem arises when I want to put the MesosSlave somewhere in the internet, so that MesosSlave and MesosMaster shall communicate through public IPs

My conf is the following:

```
              Internet                                                                          My Infra

      .----------------------.                   .-----------------.    .-----------------.              .-------------------------------------------------.
      |    Mesos Slave VM    |                   |  Front Machine  |    |      Proxy      |              |                     Tool-VM                     |
      |    178.22.17.248     |                   |  39.224.147.94  |    |    10.2.0.57    |              |                   10.1.10.176                   |
      |----------------------|                   |  my.domain.com  |    |-----------------|              |           192.168.5.1 (docker bridge)           |
      |                      |                   |-----------------|    |                 |              |-------------------------------------------------|
      |                      |                   |                 |    |                 |              |                                                 |
      |       __________     |                   | __________      |    | __________      |              |                 .-----------------------------. |
      |      [_...__..5051.°]|                   |[_..5050.__...°] |<---|[_..5050.__...°] |<------------^|                 |   Mesos-Master Container    | |
      |                      |                   |                 |    |                 |              \ __________      | 192.168.5.4 (docker bridge) | |
      |                      |                   | __________      |    | __________      |              |[_..5050.__...°]^|-----------------------------| |
      |                      |                   |[_..2181.__...°] |<---|[_..2181.__...°] |<------------^|                 \ __________                  | |
      |                      |                   |                 |    |                 |              \ __________      |[_..5050.__...°]             | |
      |                      |                   |                 |    |                 |              |[_..2181.__...°]^| __________                  | |
      |                      |                   |                 |    |                 |              |                 \[_..2181.__...°]             | |
      |                      |                   |                 |    |                 |              |                 '-----------------------------' |
      '----------------------'                   '-----------------'    '-----------------'              '-------------------------------------------------'
```

However:

> My domain infra redirect everthing that arrives from outside on ports 5050 (for Mesos) and port 2181 (zookeeper) **ONLY** for requests that are addressed to the domain 'my.domain.com' (which is a virtualhost of  39.224.147.94). But not for the other requests (that are arriving on 39.224.147.94).

So I try to execute the service through CLI for the moment:

1. Execute **Mesos Master**(in Mesos Master Container)

`/usr/sbin/mesos-master --ip=192.168.5.4 --work_dir=~/Mesos/mesos-0.23.0/workdir/ --zk=zk://192.168.5.4:2181/mesos --quorum=1 --log_dir=/var/log/mesos --external_log_file=/dev/stdout`

2. Execute **Marathon** (in Mesos Master Container)

`/usr/bin/marathon --zk zk://192.168.5.4:2181/marathon --master zk://my.domain.com:2181/mesos`

3. Execute **Mesos Slave** (in Mesos Slave VM)

`/usr/sbin/mesos-slave --master=my.domain.com:5050 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos/agent --port=8009  --containerizers=docker  --executor_registration_timeout=3mins --log_dir=/var/log/mesos`

The Mesos Master can see the Slave resources.
However, when I send a Job through Marathon, this job stay in a **waiting** state.

It seems that the slave is not able to communicate on the hostname of the Master, but only using it's public IP:

I have this in the Slave logs:

> New master detected at master@39.224.147.94:5050

However incoming traffic on **39.224.147.94:5050** is blocked by my infra (only **my.domain.com:5050** is accepted)

So, is it possible to create a connection between Master and Slaves, using domain names, but not IPs?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing to bee honest. What I don't understand is that you seem to use the `192.168.5.4` ip for the Master process, but it's nowhere to be found in your diagram. I'd expect to use `39.224.147.94` instead.

Furthermore, I'd recommend to use the ip addresses instead of hostname in all connection strings, you're using a mixture...

Additionally, you can try to set the `LIBPROCESS_IP` environment variable to the respective ip addresses for the agent and Marathon processes.

Another question would be why you use such an old version of Mesos... Mesos 1.1.0 is out already!